Timing of Biden's okay for Ukraine use of long-range missiles
President Biden has allowed Ukraine to use long-range missiles to strike military targets deep inside Russia. This development comes immediately after Olaf Scholz phone conversation with Vladimir Putin, and Volodymyr Zelenskyy own admission that the war will probably end soon after the new (old) US administration (re)takes the office.
Previously Biden administration resisted Ukrainian demands for using long-range missiles, motivating it by the risk of escalation of the conflict:

Biden had remained opposed, determined to hold the line against any escalation that he felt could draw the US and other NATO members into direct conflict with Russia.

Suddenly taking such a risk in his lame duck period is somewhat surprising. I also wonder, whether there is any connection with the Scholz-Putin call, and strengthening the Ukrainian position prior to the ceasefire/peace talks.
Has the Biden administration provided any justification for the timing of the announcement (i.e., in lame duck period, and right after the Scholz-Putin call)?

The North Korean troops on the ground? I've seen on the news (CBS) that was the reason.

@DogBoy37 one answer already says it. And they have been there for quite some time. Also, so what? How do a few thousand make difference?

@sfxedit if you have issues with the content of the question, the comments section is to express them. Do not edit questions without the author's consent just because you disagree with the views expressed in them.

It is acceptable for reviewers and moderators to make changes to any Q&A to bring it within the acceptable guidelines of this SE. (You can always easily roll back any changes you do not approve or, dispute it at meta if the Q&A is locked). Note that I made the changes to your Q because it already has 2 close votes in its current form, and I was being helpful with the edit made - in its current form, it is likely to be closed. It is upto you to decide what is more important to you - that this Q be up and receive answer or be shutdown. (I'll abstain from voting if you don't trust my intentions)

You don't want speculation in answers but you engage in plenty of speculation in your Q. I feel this isn't a real Q but a prop to tell us what you think about this matter. See https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6996/18373

@264champagnebottlesonice again, the actual question is in bold font, and is pretty factual. The rest is my attempts at rational explanation of this move, and no one so far suggested anything better. Most of the objections here seem to be grounded solely in the inane belief that "our politicians would never do such a thing".

@Alexei I reverted to the original form of the Q., since I am against unilateral changes of the text: if you want to suggest changes, it is always better to propose them in the comments section, to check whether they agree with what the authors meant, and let the authors to change the Q. themselves. This is the second time the Q. was edited bypassing this basic politeness. I understand that some of my propositions may be controversial, and I would have been far more willing to modify them, if treated respectfully.

What is with all these close votes? The question is Has the Biden administration provided any justification for the timing of the announcement. That's a yes/no question which I literally cannot see any way to interpret as opinion-based. Voting to reopen.

I think the question is on-topic and can be answered. I did not downvote it, but I think the part suggesting possible answers belongs in the post. Also "Suddenly taking such a risk in his lame duck period looks somewhat irresponsible. "  somewhat begs for the "The primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or discredit a specific political cause" close reason.

@Wagthemainstreammediadog Yes, you are right. I should have proposed the change in the comments. I have just did that.

@Alexei thanks for understanding.

I mean unless he outright says so, any possible answers can only be speculative. Also there's a good chance that this has nothing to do with U.S. internal politics, but is a reaction to Russian war efforts.
For example since Western countries have, for a long time restricted the usage of their weaponry for purposes within Ukraine, Russia changed it's strategy and often launched attacks from Russian territory so that they became increasingly hard to defend against without being able to strike the aggressor.
Hence Biden has already permitted Ukraine to attack some targets within Russia.
Since then Ukraine has taken some land in the Kursk region, while Russia has apparently recently gathered large amounts of North Korean troops within it's borders, that apparently already attack Ukrainian (and depending on the source also Russian targets...). So Ukraine has for a long time argued that they need those kinds of weapons and that they are effectively fighting with one hand behind their back.
So rather than a "surprising", "early inauguration present" for Trump, that might be a long discussed reaction to a changing situation that has nothing to do with U.S. internal politics and people might just have not been paying as much attention to that conflict as the president and his advisors (kinda is also part of their job).
Also depending on whom you ask that is somewhere between a threat leading directly to WWIII or "too little too late".
Like apparently the ATACMS are actually to short in range to strike against Russian-fired glide bombs. Though argue that even just the ability to make a few deeper strikes would require Russia to react and disperse their troops making it at least a little harder.
Edit:

Ukrainian President Volodymyr Zelenskyy was in the U.S. back in September, he presented President Joe Biden with a list of targets that he wanted to hit. Biden didn't refuse the request outright. Effectively, they agreed to keep discussing it. Finally, though, that decision was made to grant Ukraine this long-standing request, to allow them to use these long-range missiles deeper inside Russia. At least part of the reason for the rather abrupt policy change here is that the U.S. viewed the deployment of North Korean troops to Russia.
Thousands of them, in fact, as an escalation, one that merited some sort of response. So, this, at least in theory, is part of that response granting source

So North Korean troops were indeed cited as the reason.

It seems like a simple attempt to allow for Ukraine to have more options before Trump takes office and not an attempt to let them win before that happens.

It is unlikely that Ukraine regains all of its territories before any
Trump-sponsored ceasefire/peace deal. Biden authorization then might
be the last-ditch effort to help Ukraine to regain as much as possible
before the war ends.

While this is true is is also unlikely that a deal will be accepted by both sides as it will likely not be what they want.

Biden might try to escalate the conflict and thus scuttle Scholz and
Trump's efforts to end the war.

This just seems like a conspiracy theory as Russia has done more to escalate the conflict then anyone else with all the attacks they have done on civilians.

(Far fetched) Biden hopes to drag NATO and the US inn war and use it
as a pretext to stay in power.

This also sounds like a conspiracy theory as the election has already been decided and the transition of power is in progress. There is nothing that can happen at to stop that and any conflicts will just pass on to Trump.
In short this is the last opportunity to give them this option as it is unlikely to happen when Trump takes office and he could even work to remove this new permission.


Has the Biden administration provided any justification for the timing of the announcement (i.e., in lame duck period, and right after the Scholz-Putin call)?

First, the White House was reluctant to comment, with no official announcement of the kind you imply for days.

The Biden administration hasn't publicly confirmed the ATACMS policy change. State Department spokesperson Matthew Miller told journalists at a Monday briefing he would not confirm or deny approval for ATACMS use inside Russia, but said the U.S. response to Russian and North Korean military cooperation in the war "would be firm."

Likewise:

In a Monday [Nov 18] morning briefing in Rio de Janeiro, U.S. Deputy National Security Adviser Jonathan Finer evaded questions from reporters about Biden's [ATACMS] authorization.
"I'm not confirming any decisions that have or have not been made about U.S. assistance when it comes to these operational questions," Finer said.   "I will say, with regard to the comments that came out of Russia, the fire was lit by Russia's invasion of Ukraine."

Eventually,

The White House for the first time on Monday [Nov 25] publicly acknowledged easing restrictions over Ukraine's use US-supplied longer-range missiles, allowing Kyiv's forces to strike targets deeper inside Russia.
National Security Council spokesperson John Kirby said Washington "did change the guidance" over Army Tactical Missile System (ATACMS) missiles, "and we gave them guidance that they could use them to strike these particular types of targets."
"Right now, they are able to use ATACMS to defend themselves in an immediate-need basis. And right now, understandably, that's taken place in around Kursk, in the Kursk Oblast," he told reporters, referring to the Russian territory Ukrainian forces have been operating in since August.
"I'd let the Ukrainians speak to their use of ATACMS, and their targeting procedures, and what they're using them for, and how well they're doing," he added.

There's the full WH press conference of Nov 25 transcript available, but it doesn't say much more about this.
There's not been a lot of these strikes, despite all the press. Perhaps two strikes by Ukraine with ATACMS in Bryansk and on a airfield in Kursk, to date. Commentators who were saying that their impact would be limited because of limited supply were probably correct.
BTW, I don't see why the WH would have to be terribly concerned about the Scholz-Putin call, of all things. Despite some (ahem, CNN) headlines that the call was "ending Western isolation" for Putin (headline that they've changed in the meantime, by the way), little of that sort came out from the summary of the call. And Scholz has now visited Ukraine again. The call appears to have been more of an attempt to placate domestic opposition (ahead of the elections) that Germany was not doing enough diplomacy. Anyhow, no WH press corps journalist seems to have made the connection with ATACMS to ask something like that. However, based on Dec 2 press conference with Kirby, the general gist of what the WH is doing is (in their opinion):

White House national security spokesman John Kirby emphasized Monday [Dec 2] that the Biden administration’s job is to put Ukraine in the best position of strength to give Zelenskyy leverage when negotiations begin. He underlined that it’s Zelenskyy “who gets to decide if and when he’s ready to negotiate, and he gets to decide what if anything he’s willing to negotiate.”


I don't see why the WH would have to be terribly concerned about the Scholz-Putin call, of all things - I don't know how much info filters to the US, but Zelenskyy's reaction was immediate (as the Q. points out): he denounced Scholz call and admitted that the ceasefire is likely around the corner. Now he has gone even further, suggesting that Ukraine might temporarily cede territories to Russia. This represents a big change - judging by the hysterical reactions that we have seen in this community at the very suggestion of such an outcome - oft labeled "Russian propaganda".

no WH press corps journalist seems to have made the connection with ATACMS to ask something like that - IMHO journalists' job is to report the facts, rather than tell people what to think (which connections to make in this case.) Anyhow, I expect critical analysis of facts (rather than simply reporting the government spin) to be on topic in this community.

Biden did so because he lost the election. Trump was campaigning on quickly ending the war, if Biden had sent weapons earlier then Trump would be able to campaign on the Dems starting wars etc and expanding this Ukraine conflict instead of trying to end it.
Trumps plan for stopping war in Ukraine is to demand a ceasefire and then to negotiate a peace treaty. If Ukraine didn’t agree to it he’d cut their aid. If Russia didn’t agree to it, he would increase Ukrainian aid. This is a high level IQ move because it puts Putin in a bind — either he stops hostilities, giving Ukraine time to regroup and recuperate, which hurts him long time. Or he doesn’t stop and Ukraine gets more weapons and Putin will seem even more of a warmonger. In this regard, Trump masterfully appears both as a peacemaker while also essentially advancing same policies as Biden

"Biden did so because he lost the election." There's no way to know this for sure. He could have chosen to do it after the election regardless whether he won or lost.

"Trumps plan for stopping war in Ukraine is to demand a ceasefire and then to negotiate a peace treaty. If Ukraine didn’t agree to it he’d cut their aid. If Russia didn’t agree to it, he would increase Ukrainian aid." Has Trump actually stated that this is his plan? Specifically, the part about increasing aid to Ukraine if Russia won't agree to his terms?

Come to think of it, I'm unsure of the relevance of the entire second paragraph to the question.

Biden HAS already sent weapons earlier, the action in question is permitting the usage of the full potential of these weapons as previously attacks deep within Russian territory were off limits, which prompted Russia to move it's artillery out of range of what Ukraine is allowed to target... Also people in the U.S. don't seem to care much about foreign policy, but for people paying attention: We already were at that point after Crimea AND before the invasion. There were ceasefires (violated constantly), there were peace talks and negotiations (to no avail) and then there was a Russian invasion

2/ Like practically this means that Putin has gotten yet another slice of Ukraine. Also to what audience to you plan to make Putin look like a warmongerer? Like he unilaterally invaded another country in plain sight. Who thinks he is had realized that at the very least in 2022 and who still thinks he isn't... well they aren't paying attention, but why should that change?
